# Apache does not install on FreeBSD 8.4

Tags: apache, freebsd

today i tried to install a Webserver on FreeBSD 8.4... I updated the ports, but apache gives me this message:

```
pkg_create: make_dist: tar command failed with code 256
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/p5-Locale-gettext.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/misc/help2man.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/misc/help2man.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/autoconf.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/apache24.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/apache24.
```

How can I resolve?

Thank you and sorry for bad english

Comment: Maybe http://superuser.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably in the line before the error cascade you posted.

The error is not in apache but in p5-Locale-gettext. Most likely it is missing some files.

Workaround:

```
cd /usr/ports/misc/help2man
make config
```

disable the NLS option

...and try again.

Comment: Awesome! It works! But I got another problem installing PHP 5.3

{configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.}

Answer (score 0):

After this, i tried to install PHP 5.3, but i got this message

```
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
```

And it says to give you the config.log
Here you are:

http://notepad.cc/share/c8K36t3G3x

Comment: try to reinstall textproc/libxml2. Something is wrong on your system.